# PPTK, setting camera position

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, point-clouds, pptk

I try to setting camera position of pptk, with this method:

```
xyz = pptk.rand(100, 3)
v = pptk.viewer(xyz)
v.set(lookat=[0,0,0])
```

this working well, the camera position change.
But when I left-clik on it, to move the point cloud, the camera position return to the original position

Do you have an idea how to maintain the camera position
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please send the look-at coordinates as a tuple (0,0,0) instead of a list [0,0,0].

v.set(lookat=(0,0,0))

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug too. I'm currently working around it by first using the mouse wheel to move in/out on the point cloud before clicking; then the look at position doesn't change.